# facebook sso 3.1.1 linking with non arc enabled project

Tags: iphone, facebook

i started non arc enabled project and drag and dropped /Users/imacfghdf/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders folder in project by unselecting for just refrencing it in xocde project.

actually i want to implement facebook SDK 3.1.1 for non arc enabled project and also without using full source folder project into my project..

i want static linking as i hope this only making problems for me if any help then please as if any one have same problem like me..

but getting error as following:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

as i found by googling that deprecatedHeaders uses facebookSDK folder in it so i just used but 
found with this problem:
my code is:

## import "Facebook.h"

Comment: to include fb dialogs i reference deprecated headers where facebooksdk .framework,FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle,FacebookSDKResources.bundle was already there working fine before adding deprecated headers after adding that nothing was working and i created copy of the project and deleted extra frameworks that effected my main copy and whole work spoiled and now nothing is working...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also drag in these:

~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework

~/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FacebookSDKResources.bundle

For more info, please see the getting started doc at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

The deprecated headers are needed only if you want to use Facebook dialogs (feed, requests) alongside the newer APIs. If you do not need to use Facebook dialogs then you don't need to include the deprecated headers.